# What is the advantage of initializing static variable in a static constructor instead of direct assignment of value

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0, constructor

In the below-mentioned code, there are two ways of assigning the value of the static variable 'RateOfInterest'.

1. By directly assigning the value.
2. By assigning in a static constructor.

*I believe for multiple objects of the 'Customer' class, 'RateOfInterest' will have only one memory allocation using either approach. (Please correct me if I am wrong).*

**Is there any specific advantage of one approach over the other.**

```
class Customer
{
    int AccNo;
    static int RateOfInterest;
    //static int RateOfInterest = 10;    // Approach 1
    static Customer()
    {
        RateOfInterest = 10;          // Approach 2
    }
    public Customer(int AccNo)
    {
        this.AccNo = AccNo;
    }
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"AccNo : {AccNo}, Rate : {RateOfInterest}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Static fields are initialized before the static constructor is executed, thats all. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they will be compiled in to same thing. so no difference,

That's not private constructor. that's [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced

I use static constructor when by directly assigning value, the line becomes too long (that's opinion based) or when I need multiple lines to initialize a value.

Comment: when your code is compiled, it will use static constructor to initialize static fields, properties. that's why I said there is no difference. please read the link from msdn to see other properties of static constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, the two approaches have no difference.

If you want to assign a literal value, like `10`, then assigning it directly at the declaration is faster.

But if your variable's initialization is more complex, like this:

```
val = new MyClass();
val.A = 1;
val.B = "Hi";
val.SomeMethod();
val.AnotherMethod();
```

You should put it in a static constructor.